# Unity c# - Error in a script that should change text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a level select menu. Here is a screenshot of my layout: [image] To make this work, this is my script for making it happen:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChooseLevel : MonoBehaviour
{

    string[] levelNames;
    int i = 0;


    public Button addIndex;
    public Button subtractIndex;
    public Text levelChooser;

    string lvlName = "";

    void Start()
    {
        levelNames = PlayMenu.levelNames;

        addIndex.onClick.AddListener(delegate () { i += 1; });
        subtractIndex.onClick.AddListener(delegate () { i -= 1; });

    }

    void Update()
    {
        i = Mathf.Clamp(i, 0, levelNames.Length);
        lvlName = levelNames[i];
        levelChooser.text = lvlName;
    }

}
```

The code is attached to the canvas and here are screen shots of the scene and a section of the inspector for the canvas:
[image]
[image]

The error i get is:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ChooseLevel.Update () (at Assets/ChooseLevel.cs:28)
```

Comment: Do you ever create a `ChooseLevel` object?

Comment: you should never, ever, ever use 'SerializeField" for any reason. simply mark the field "public".  it's that simple.  that's if you're absolutely sure you want that behavior

Comment: this code "Mathf.Clamp(i, 0, levelNames.Length);" is meaningless.  you probably meant "i = Mathf.Clamp(i, 0, levelNames.Length);"

Comment: note that the pattern is often "i = i % length" to make it wrap (but, take care with negatives)

Comment: note that you have `string lvlName`.  you never, ever, do this with strings.  initialize it to a blank string by default.  `string lvlName = ""`

Answer (score 2):

You declare your string right above `void Start()`, but don't initialize it. (Implicitly `null`)

```
string lvlName;
```

So then when you go in `Update()` for the first time, the value of `lvlName` is `null`.

```
void Update()
{
    levelChooser.text = lvlName; //null the first time 
    lvlName = levelNames[i]; //THEN it's changed
    Mathf.Clamp(i, 0, levelNames.Length);
}
```

So depending on your game logic you must either FIRST assign to `lvlName` or initialize it with an empty string. I guess

```
void Update()
{
    i = Mathf.Clamp(i, 0, levelNames.Length); //FIRST clamp. Thanks to Joe Blow for pointing out that it never gets reassigned.
    lvlName = levelNames[i]; //then update lvlName
    levelChooser.text = lvlName; //then Change the text. 
}
```

should work fine. Also make sure that `i` doesn't hit the exact value `levelNames.Length` but I think that logic is okay. You'll notice when you get an out-of-bounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a small error in another script.